# Understanding the scope of a typedef in two structs (functors)

Tags: c++

If I `typedef` some type within a struct (functor), is the scope of the `typedef` local to the struct?

Consider the following example where I have typdef'ed foo to be an `int` and a `double` in the two separate functors. Is this example correct?

```
template <typename T> 
struct firstfunctor 
{ 
  typedef int foo; 

  foo operator()(const foo& a, const foo& b) 
  { 
    return /*whatever*/
  } 
}; 

template <typename T> 
struct secondfunctor 
{ 
  typedef double foo; 

  foo operator()(const foo& a, const foo& b) 
  { 
    return /*whatever*/
  } 
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, typedefs are scoped, and you define the *member* types `firstfunctor::foo` and `secondfunctor::foo`, respectively.

Comment: @Pubby: Maybe. Perhaps member type *name* is a good term... and also a reminder that you'll need to say `typename firstfunctor<T>::foo` a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the typedefs are scoped. You will have to specify the scope when using them.

This applies to objects, classes and libraries. Scope is usually limited to what is defined inside a set of `{ }`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

This goes for functions and namespaces too.

---

The type would be `firstfunctor<>::foo` qualified. You can make it private, although C++11's `auto` allows you to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and you can use those typedefs for interesting meta-programming concepts whereby you are passed in a class to a template (or even a template in this case) and can use

`typename X<T>::foo`

to get your "dynamic" type.

where X is your templated template parameter.